# How do I passively detect a dropped iPhone or Android?

Tags: android, iphone, mono, xamarin, gyroscope

I want to tell if someone broke their iPhone screen by dropping it [so I can open a special UI in emergencies](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/74875/2139) like this.

I don't want to waste the battery and spin up an internal gyroscope all the time, so is there any way to passively detect a dropped iPhone or Android?

Answer (score 0):

Drop it into a hard pillow. It will simulate the impact of a phone hitting the ground. But, I would suggest trying to use the accelerometer on the device instead of the gyroscope, only because it tracks speed.